# invalid syntax: my code looks the same as that in the book

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
states = [
    'oregon': 'OR',
    'florida': 'FL',
    'california': 'CA',
    'new york': 'NY',
    'michigan': 'MI'
]
```

when I run code above, terminal always say:

```
'oregon': 'OR',
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But I just copy the code in a book, not exactly copy&paste, but type them manually and they look the same. I don't know what's going wrong.
hope someone can help me with that. thanks!!

Comment: You should use a dictionary syntax   `states = {}`

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where I would like to see an image of code... from the book, specifically. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using the wrong syntax to declare a dictionary, specifically the wrong sort of brackets. Use `[]` to declare a list, and `{}` to declare a dictionary. Like this:

```
states = {
    'oregon': 'OR',
    'florida': 'FL',
    'california': 'CA',
    'new york': 'NY',
    'michigan': 'MI'
}
```